# python regex for matching "[ab[cd]]fg[hi]]"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

```
s = "[ab[cd]]fg[hi]"
```

I want to get the substring `[ab[cd]]`
The problem really is that there can be any number of open and closed brackets. For reference [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/) is the problem I am trying to solve.

if I use `re.search("\[(.*)\]", s)`, it matches the last `]`

If I use `re.search("\[(.*?)\]", s)`, it stops at the first `]`

I want the regex to match `[ab[cd]]` for string `[ab[cd]]fg[hi]` and match `[ab[cd[ef]]]` for string `[ab[cd[ef]]]f[hi]`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How about ```\[\w+\[\w+\]\]```?

Comment: I don't know how many nested open and close brackets it may contain.

Comment: So, what's the differentiating factor between picking `[ab[cd]]` and `fg[hi]` or `[ab[cd]]fg[hi]` for that matter?

Comment: As I walk through the string, if I encounter a '[', then I need to find its matching '] and do some processing. This is for a programming question: https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/

Comment: My suggestion is to separate the search for the multipliers and the corresponding "strings" and then replace the occurrences using recursion. I coded a working example and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you know in advance a limit to the possible amount of bracket nesting, it's not possible with the `re` module - but, the `regex` module can do it via recursion:

```
\[(?:[a-z]|(?R))*\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/Al0jny/1

With `re`, you'd have to manually try to match the possible nesting levels, eg:

```
\[(?:[a-z]|\[[a-z]*\])*\]
```

Comment: This will work. Let me give this a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the input. But, based on the input on your referenced links, maybe it can help.

```
(\d+)|(\[[a-z]\])|(\[[a-z]+\])|([a-z]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/RRTLIU/1

Or if you want to ignore the square brackets, you can use this `regex`:

```
(\d+)|\[([a-z])\]|\[([a-z]+)\]|([a-z]+)
```